# Comparing a String to String extract in android

Tags: java, android, string, types, comparison

I am obtaining the title of a Context Menu Item then comparing it to a string. The code below does not seem to work as expected, why?

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getTitle().equals(String.valueOf(R.string.item_edit_text))){ // <-- compared to string extract
        Toast.makeText(this, "Match",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Match",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

The `item.getTitle` results in "Edit" and `R.string.item_edit_text` is "Edit". So why the above code results in "No Match"?

The code below seems to work fine, however,

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getTitle().equals("Edit")){ // <--- Compared to hardcoded string
        Toast.makeText(this, "Match",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Match",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: try `getString(R.string.item_edit_text)` instead of `String.valueOf(R.string.item_edit_text)`.

Comment: That does work, any idea why?

Comment: Still trying to find the exact reason. I thought `String.valueOf()` would also work but its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`R.string.item_edit_text` is probably of `EditText` type.

When you write :

```
String.valueOf(R.string.item_edit_text)
```

it returns finally  `R.string.item_edit_text.toString()` but  `R.string.item_edit_text.toString()` doesn't return 
the text of the `EditText`.

You should rather do `R.string.item_edit_text.getText().toString()` to apply tge toString() on the Editable instance returned by `getText()`.

You could so write it :

```
if (item.getTitle().equals(R.string.item_edit_text.getText().toString())){
```

Or:

```
if (item.getTitle().equals(getString(R.string.item_edit_text))){
```

Comment: Based on @jackjay comment, tracing down the code I came to the same conclusion. But if I perform `Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(R.string.item_edit_text),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` I get the same text.

Comment: Look at the signature of  `makeText ()` : `Toast makeText (Context context, 
                int resId, 
                int duration)` It takes as second parameter the resId and not the text contained in. The retrieval of the text on the resource is performed in`makeText()`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

This is what i found and it seems explaining.

The `getString(int)` method in Context and its subclasses (like Activity) are meant specifically to look up a string resource that was included in your app, and it takes a string resource id as a parameter to know which resource to find. Again, in Java this parameter appears to be just a normal integer.

`String.valueOf(int)` is entirely different. It is a Java library function that takes an integer and produces a String representation of that integer, e.g. `String.valueOf(5)` returns "5". It is not useful for getting Android string resources.

Comment: I am not going to do that because what i thought was wrong. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`String.valueOf()` Returns the string representation of the int argument that you pass into it. And you have passed an Resource id to the method. So the method will that method will return the String representation  not the resource as you expected. You should use `getString(R.string.item_edit_text)`.